# Media gallery application using Flex to run on standalone Flash Player

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

How can i design a 3D carousel for video/images to run on standalone Flash Player on my Desktop?  I am using Flash Builder 4 to develop this as a mxml application, but found that it doesn't allow access to local filesystem. My specific requirement is that I want it running on the local computer and in SWF files viewed in a user's browser. Is there a sample code to do what I am trying to do? This application has states and transition, like one state for a video gallery and one state for a image gallery

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking a 3D carousel example and modifying it to use video instead of images?